# Force contenteditable content to be inside div or p

Tags: html, contenteditable, editing

does anyone know how to force a the content of a contenteditable div do be surrounded by a div or a p? If the content of the contenteditable is an empty div - selecting it with a range works on Firefox for example but on chrome the text is inserted before the div. I need the text

```
HTML:
<div id="edit" contenteditable="true"><div id="insert"></div></div>

Tried this but the results are very inconsistent cross browser:

var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('insert'));

var selection = window.getSelection();
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

The second question here is if this is somehow possible for an empty contentEditable, could this be also used for manually inserting newlines to be sure never to get <br/> tags instead of a new div or p ?

Thanks

**Update**

It seems the following works at some degree:

```
<div id="edit" contenteditable="true"><div id="insert"><br/></div></div>
```

With the additional <br/> Firefox, Chrome, Safari all generate an single empty line where all input ends up inside the div, but Internet Explorer (tested Version 9) shows two empty lines. If there is no other solution available - any ideas how to fix this without using browser detection?

Comment: I've been searching for an answer on this for well over a month to fix a bunch of bugs still in Firefox. Thx u thx u thx u.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `br` tag in your css file.

```
br {
    display:block;
    clear: both;
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

I am not quite sure if `em` will work. If not, you'll have to try `px` format too.